# Adding row table for each ID in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, rows

I am trying to make a website for a radio, and I want to make a page which will contain the playlist of the radio. I made a table with rows and columns (Song Name | DJ) and here is the code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <h3>Radio PlayList</h3>
    <tr>
        <th>Song Name</th>
        <th>DJ</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nil</td>
        <td>Nil</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make a MySQL table that contains the names of the songs and their DJ. I want to make it so, for every ID (song name | dj) a new row is added, something like this:

```
Song Name     |    DJ

Song 1        |    DJ 1

Song 2        |    DJ 2

Song 3        |    DJ 3
```

Comment: Are you asking, how to create mysql database?  Or are you having issues inserting data into a table with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you had already data inserted into your database table. In order to create a row you need to loop the records in the result set returned by the query.

Check example here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your question.

You want to create a table? Like this?

```
CREATE TABLE songs(
    id_song INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    song_name CHAR(255),
    song_dj CHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT prim_key_songs
    PRIMARY KEY (id_song)
);
```

Comment: I am not talking about a MYSQL table, I am talking about this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp   I already have the data in the MYSQL table, but I want to create a row for each song and it's dj, like, lets say I only have a song called "Song1", and on the website, there is a row called "Song1", but I add another song called "Song2" but I don't know how to make the script create a new row in the website table for each song...